# Is a User still a User if files are copied to a new system with same Username?

Tags: gnome, permissions, network-manager, password, vpn

If I use something like Clonezilla to clone a system to another drive and use that and also copied the ~/home/user files separately, the username is still nominally the same.

I even then (probably unwisely) do a chown -r for the new home folder, does this make a difference to permissions?

The reason being that I had a helluva time with VPN passwords not being recognized or stored or persistent until in nm-connection-manager I clicked on the icon next to the password and save for all users.

So I wonder if there are two users here, one for the old copied home files, or the clonezilla ones, and a new user on the new system but with the same username . In short is JoeBloe the same JoeBloe when copied to another system, what's in a name?

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and 5.13.0-35-generic
and gnome apt-cache show gnome-shell | grep Version
Version: 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2
Version: 3.36.1-5ubuntu1

Supplementary question, is it safe to store vpn password for 'other users'?

Comment: A fully updated 20.04 system is 20.04.4 you should run an update and upgrade to bring your system up to date.

Comment: yes I have had that sort of comment before, thanks, but it seems to necessitate a dist upgrade and my best option was for a new live CD install and the option it gave for keep home and parrallel install. too risky and complicated for me. I do regular update/upgrades. I came across "do-release-update is for updating between releases like 18.04, 20.04, not the minor versions like 20.04.x. " and sudo do-release-upgrade r completely screwed my system last month, I had a cloned backup I restored from.

Comment: I would have done an update/upgrade in the last 2 weeks.

Comment: I have not idea where you are getting a release upgrade destroys systems.  Please supply the source of this info.

Comment: my own personal experience, I did the do-release-update -r and it booted to the not unfamiliar for AMD users blank screen and blinking cursor or, when it did boot, the not altogether unfamiliar pixellated desktop screen. are you saying you know of successful release upgrades for AMD Ryzen users?

Answer (score 3):

> is JoeBloe the same JoeBloe when copied to another system

Not necessarily. The system identifies a user through a number, the **uid**. "JoeBloe" will be the same "JoeBloe" when copied to another system in case the uid of the user is still the same.

In your case, where you clone a system, definitely "JoeBloe" will still have the same uid, so "be" the same user.

See the uid of the current user in the output of `id`. The command `id JoeBloe` will show uid and groups of the user JoeBlue.

Comment: The system gets all this info from `/etc/passwd`. Read `man 5 passwd`

Comment: @waltinator Yes, but not sure if this is essential information to answer this question.

Comment: I am awaiting a new power switch for my old system that I cloned from so I cannot check if the id's are the same. but if on my newer system does chown JoeBloe make the owner the id that I get from id JoeBlie. I see from man chown it takes an id, so perhaps my mistake was using the name and not the id.   " If only an owner  (a  user   name  or  numeric  user  ID)  is given, that user is made the owner of each     given file, and the files' group is not changed. "

Comment: further id user gives me uid=1000(JoeBloe) gid=1000(JoeBloe). It still begs the question ,. which I only guess is related to permissions, why I needed to allow for the vpn password to be shared by 'all users' to get any stability  in vpn and even internet/ethernet  connectivity, which is now working quite well.

Comment: actually if I did a chown and only used username, then perhaps the old group, being root is not the same as the root group of an upgraded cloned system? for 'id root' I get, without requiring sudo or root access permissions, uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

Comment: On Ubuntu, the first user created, i.e., the one installing the system, acquires UID 1000. The root user indeed has uid=0. The way Ubuntu is configured, accessing this information about users indeed does not require administrator permissions.